# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ which contains $N_G(P)$ for some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime. Let $H$ be a subgroup of
>   $G$ which contains $N_G(P)$ for some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.
>   Suppose $P \subseteq H^g$ for some $g \in G$. Prove that $g \in H$.

With the assumptions I can prove that $N_G(H)=H$. What should I do then?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: DO you understand what does the question mean?

Comment: No. Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $P\trianglelefteq N_G(P)\subseteq H\subseteq G$. Observe that $P$ is a sylow $p$ subgroup of $H$ and by hypothesis $P\subseteq H^{g}$, which implies $P^{g^{-1}}\subseteq H$. Thus both $P, P^{g^{-1}}$ are sylow $p$ subgroups of $H$ and hence they are conjugate, i.e there exists an $h\in H$ such that $P=P^{g^{-1}h}$. Thus $g^{-1}h\in N_G(P)\subseteq H$, which implies $g^{-1}\in H$. Thus $g\in H$.

Comment: Spacing seems to improve if you use `{}^{g}H`: compare $P\subseteq ^{g}H$ to $P\subseteq {}^g H$.

Comment: @Pedro, thanks, that is nice to know.

Comment: To change $\;H^g\;$ for $\;^gH\;$ seems to make things less clear, and I can't see what's the advantage of this notation, im particular when used with the subset sign: it looks like $\;\subset\;$ is being raised to $\;g\;$...pretty weird.

Comment: @DonAntonio, ahh i did not even notice, somehow i am used to writing conjugation that way, but i am sure the idea is clear.

Comment: The idea is clear, the notation much less. Just compare between $\;^gP\;$ or even $\;{}^{g}P\;$ and $\;P^g\;$ ...on the left, $\;g\;$ appears very far away.

Comment: Anyway, we're given $\;P\subset H^g\;$ and $\;P\le H\implies P^g\le H^g\;$ , so both $\;P\,,\,P^g\;$ are subgroups...of $\;H^g\;$ . How did you get that they are subgroups of $\;H\;$ ?